# How to convert rows into columns in Google Spreadsheets?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet in Google Docs with two data rows and lots of columns like so:

[image]

Is it possible to easily convert these rows into two columns and lots of rows (obviously retaining all information and formulas)? In other words, to something like this:

```
 19.9.2009   967,15 €
 28.9.2009   950,78 €
12.11.2009   942,03 €
..           ..
```

There's probably a neat mathematical term for such a conversion, but I don't remember which (matrix something?). Feel free to suggest a better name for the question.

**Edit**: To clarify, ultimately I want to get rid of the original (two row) version and continue working on the converted one. TRANSPOSE(), [mentioned by Al Everett](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/6935/how-to-convert-rows-into-columns-in-google-spreadsheets/6937#6937), got me very close but not quite there. I want the raw data in the transposed version, not cells that *mirror* the original ones.

Answer (score 125, accepted):

If you're using the "new" Google Spreadsheets, in the "Edit" tab menu, under "Paste special", the last menu voice is "Paste transposed": it does exactly what you need in a single task.

Comment: Hmm. But there doesn't seem to be "Paste transposed" option [in "Paste special" menu](http://i.stack.imgur.com/2J09b.png). Are you perhaps talking about Excel? This question is about Google Spreadsheets.

Comment: It's there in new sheets, was not available in the previous version, so will only be in older ones if you have converted them.

Comment: Ah, yes. I tried with a new spreadsheet and there's indeed ["Paste transpose" option](http://i.stack.imgur.com/SSww1.png)!

Comment: Thank you. `Edit` > `Paste special` > `Paste transposed` (last option).

Answer (score 35):

If you're using the old Google Spreadsheets, you want to use the TRANSPOSE() function. ([Google help: Array functions](http://docs.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=71291))

In the upper left cell where you want this to appear, enter `=TRANSPOSE(A5:Z6)` (or whatever your data range happens to be).

If you want the raw data back, you can copy and paste the values into a fresh set of cells. (Highlight the cells you want to copy. Choose "Edit | Copy". Put your cursor on a new, empty cell. Choose "Edit | Paste values only".)

Comment: While this was definitely the best answer when it was written, the one from @user68665 let's you skip a few steps with the new Google Spreadsheets.

Comment: @kevin: True enough, and I'll edit it to reflect it's for the old Google Spreadsheets. But only the Asker can change the "accept" mark.

Comment: This is also not going to retain the formulas.